# Terraform version upgrade

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

**New to Terraform**

I am currently working on upgrading the terraform from version 0.12 to version 0.13.

Current Status

1. tfstate is present in s3 with versioning enabled.
2. the services are deployed in ecs.

Here is what I have done so far,

1. updated the modules and sub modules to latest version 0.13
2. updates the necessary configuration to latest version 0.13

### What I want to do now?

since the current resources are deployed using version 0.12, I first want to test the deployment for one of the services say service A using version 0.13, so if that goes well I then want to move ahead with the remaining ones.

### Help Needed

1. How do I make the deployment for the services (service A for example) without affecting the other services?

*Going through few of the document on which is related to* [state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/list.html)  , I found this is the one which is supposed to help me do so, but I am *exactly not sure how to approach* this since it is my **very first time working on the upgrades** and don't want to mess up which is already working fine.

Comment: Do they each have separate state files? If so then it's a case of applying out one of them and seeing that it's fine before rolling out the others. If not then this is one of the reasons why it's strongly encouraged to minimise blast radius with Terraform and separate things out as much as possible.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR currently for the serviceA, from executing the command `terraform state list |grep "serviceA", I got following output. So, I think this is seprate. Please correct me if I am wrong
>module.serviceA.module.ecs_alb_service_task.aws_ecs_service.ignore_changes_task_definition[0]
> module.serviceA.random_integer.subnet.

Comment: @whoami the whole idea of using IaaC (e.g. Terraform) is to been able to reliable reconstruct the infrastructure. You've done the needed steps, if I were you I would upgrade them directly, you should already have the code for the 0.12 version that tyou can always reconstruct. Unless you are using a unique environment, which is not adivsable.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar currently I have different workspace for dev and production. and I just want to make sure that the upgrade for the serviceA is good enough before moving ahead. So, I would appericiate your help with proper steps if you could. (since I am new to all of this, I may sound much dumb :D).

Comment: You could use resource targeting: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/resource-targeting-in-terraform. It really seems overly cautious in this instance. If you have a dev environment, why not just deploy and verify everything works before deploying to production. And ideally you would be running `terraform plan` and verifying there are no pending changes after the Terraform upgrade anyway.

Comment: This kind of procedure for resource acceptance testing would be more necessary for a major upgrade to a provider, and not so much for a major upgrade to core Terraform. Generating a plan would be sufficient for almost any use case here.